# Syntax error in mySQL Update-Query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I try to execute the query but get an error. This is my query:

```
UPDATE 
    prepares_for_exam 
SET 
    prepares_for_exam.exam_id = product.id 
FROM 
    prepares_for_exam, 
    product 
WHERE 
    prepares_for_exam.id = product.prepares_for_exam_id
```

and I get the error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM prepares_for_exam, product WHERE prepares_for_exam.id = product.prepares_fo' at line 1

I did the Update Query 100-times with an FROM clause and never had problems... Whats my fault?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the SQL-Server syntax. In MySQL it is a little bit different.

```
UPDATE 
    prepares_for_exam 
JOIN 
    product 
ON 
    prepares_for_exam.id = product.prepares_for_exam_id
SET 
    prepares_for_exam.exam_id = product.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE 
prepares_for_exam 
SET 
prepares_for_exam.exam_id = (select product.id FROM 
prepares_for_exam JOIN product on prepares_for_exam.id = product.prepares_for_exam_id)
```